# Is there a function that replace category name with a icon?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I am using a Custom Post Type and I have a Taxonomy name "Type" this taxonomy have A y B taxonomy names.

If possible a function that remplace the name of Taxonomy with an icon or image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are characters. It's probably not what you're looking for but you could potentially paste emojis in the character field. Your other option would be to create font somewhere like [Glypther](https://glyphter.com/), install it on the site and the use CSS to assign the font to you category titles and use the related letters for the icons you want. That route would take some development and design skills.

Comment: I don´t want emojis, i want an image.

Comment: Your other option would be to create font somewhere like Glypther, install it on the site and the use CSS to assign the font to you category titles and use the related letters for the icons you want. That route would take some development and design skills.